# has any way to direct create a menuitem by coding in android

Tags: android, menuitem

MenuItem mi = new MenuItem();

like above code line, but it not support by android,  and only using 
MenuItem mi = menu.add(,,,,) ,can get a MenuItem instance, but i don't want to add a menuitem to a menu. is any way other to create a MenuItem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You arent adding any content to it by the looks of it. try something like

```
Menu i = new Menu();
i.add(R.string.menu);
```

Im not completely sure if this is how you do it as I am not able to look at the docs atm so yeah

Comment: Menu is like MenuItem ，it need to implement Menu's anonymous inner type.

Comment: it's like this:

MenuItem m = new MenuItem() {
    
    Override
    public MenuItem setVisible(boolean visible) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return null;
    }
    
    Override
    public MenuItem setTitleCondensed(CharSequence title) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return null;
    }
...
}